# Can the c#.net application run without .net framework?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a windows application using c#.net, and i converted it into .exe

can i run this application on another system without installing .net framework?

please clear my doubt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

C# apllications are not handled by the operating System. Its CLR(inside framework) (Common Language Runtime) who takes care about running the C# apps and also about all memory management, resource allocation, de-allocation etc. It creates a virtual layer over the OS while running the application. So you need the .NET-framework!

Comment: Wrong. IL code is compiled to machine code the first time an application is started on a PC. After that whenever the application is started the machine code is used. C# programs are **NOT** run in virtual machines. And since the CLR is used only once per installation, Ahead of time Compilation is available at the cost of universal compatibility. **EDIT:** All windows PC's since XP SP2 have .net 2+

Answer (score -1):

Its not about C#. Its about weather you want to develop managed or unmanaged applications. C# is the choice for developing managed applications which run on .NET Framework.

If you want to avoid that , you can go to Visual C++ (without .NET) development using Visual Studio.

However, .NET framework comes pre-installed with latest Os like Win 7 these days.